# Launching a bootstrap 3 modal from keyup after escape key in Safari

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I have this code snippet which fires a bootstrap modal when I press the m key:

```
   $(window).on('keyup', function(event) {
        var key = event.which,
            $element = $(event.target);
        console.log(key);
        if (key == 77) {  // m key
            $modal.modal('show');
        }
    });
```

However, when the modal appears and I hit `esc` to exit out of it, I can no longer relaunch the modal with the 'm' key, despite `$modal.modal('show');` being called. If I click on the window, the modal fires from the keyup.

This problem only happens on Safari and I have tried doing a `focus` and `click` on the window, body, and parent div but nothing seems to work.